# Как сохранить значение переменной в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Как это сделать?
Куки не предлагать, т.к. с интернетом...
localStorage, хорошая функция, но после загрузки он(JS) думает, что загрузил переменные типа char/string и выполнять математические операции с загруженным числом невозможно, можно ли как-то это исправить?
Если нет, то как тогда работать с window.name?
Просто видал, что можно как-то сохранить с помощью window.name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно взяв из `localStorage` преобразовать строчку в численый тип.

Положить значение по ключу `"myNumber"`

```
localStorage.setItem("myNumber","111");
```

Получить с использование парсинга можно так

```
var number = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("myNumber"));
```

или синтаксис покороче

```
var number = +localStorage.getItem("myNumber");
```

достаточно распространённая ситуация хранения в `localStorage` комплексных объектов.

```
//создадим объект
var obj = {
    item1: 1,
    item2: [123, "two", 3.0],
    item3:"hello"
};

var serialObj = JSON.stringify(obj); //сериализуем его в строчку

localStorage.setItem("myKey", serialObj); //запишем его в хранилище по ключу "myKey"

var returnObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myKey")) //спарсим его обратно объект
```

после `JSON.parse` мы уже имеем нормальный объект в том числе и с целочисленными переменными.

Почитать про `localStorage`:

1. [tproger.ru - LocalStorage на пальцах](https://tproger.ru/articles/localstorage/)
2. [metanit.com - Web Storage](https://metanit.com/web/javascript/12.2.php)

Comment: Благодарю, но что точно нужно писать вместо Mynumber?

Comment: @Кирилл дополнил ответ. "myNumber" это просто ключ, по какому ключу кладёте по такому и получаете. Считайте что ключ это как номер ящика в хранилище, положили свои вещи в ящик 32, получили из ящика 32. Только в данном случае используется не номер а строка.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, Вам огромное

Comment: А что если операция с переменными типа boolean, как поступать в этом случае? Так же?

Comment: @Кирилл можно вот так например `JSON.parse("true")`

Comment: @Кирилл Или так: `var result = (str == "true")`.

Comment: А "true" - это ключ? В первом

Comment: @Кирилл "true" это строка которую вы преобразуете в `boolean` тип, её можно извлечь например из `localStorage` по ключу

Comment: А, я имел ввиду, что у меня из localStorage извлекается строка "true"/"false", а не значение. И в этом заключается вопрос, как правильно извлечь?

Comment: @Кирилл `var value = localStorage.getItem("myItem") == "true";`

Comment: Спасибо, кажется, сработало